# JSF & sending parameters

Tags: jsf, parameters, javabeans

I need to send values (the input from a Textbox) as parameters to a method & I am new at JSF.

Say I have a form, linked to a managed bean

```
<h:form id="myForm">
   <h:inputText id="atribute1" value="#{myBean.atribute1}"></h:inputText>
   <h:inputText id="atribute2" value="#{myBean.atribute2}"></h:inputText>

   <h:commandButton id="btn" value="SendData" action="#{myBean.save}">
    <p:param name="param1" value="${atribute1}"/>
        <p:param name="param2" value="${atribute2}"/>
   </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

the managed bean has a "save" method (i made it here a void method, but Eclipse seems to want it to return a String??)

```
public void save() {
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();  
Map<String,String> params  = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
String param1= params.get("param1");
String param2= params.get("param2");

System.out.println("param1:"+param1+" & param2:"+param2);
}
```

This doesnt seem to do anything, I get no values printed, but i doesn't crash. So anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to act on values in save method.

You have already linked the values to be entered in textbox to backing bean via `value="#{myBean.atribute1}"` which states that vallue entered here will be available in property atribute1 of managed bean named `mybean`, when you submit the page you can acces them in save method directly.

```
public void save() {
   System.out.println("param1:"+this.attribute1+" & param2:"+this.attribute2);
}
```

make sure you have getter/setters for both properties and remove child tags from commandbutton.